# Does abseil flat_hash_map support concurrency?

Tags: c++, abseil

[Abseil](https://abseil.io/about/) is an open source C++ library maintained by Google. It is designed to be complementary to C++ std in terms of performance and/or functionality. `abseil::flat_hash_map` is *almost* the `abseil` counterpart of `std::unordered_map`. My question is: Is it possible to use `abseil::flat_hash_map` or any other abseil's hash map using multiple threads?

Comment: I doubt it.  Making any container threadsafe imposes a performance hit, even for single threaded use, which most people would want to avoid.

Comment: Thank you @PaulSanders for your comment. I am just trying to make sure. The `folly::map` (i.e., the exact same data structure from Facebook) supports concurrency.

Comment: Test it with multiple threads constantly updating the same hash_map at the same time and another thread that probes it, and see what happens? :-)

Comment: If Google are claiming comparable performance to the STL, their code is unlikely to be threadsafe.  You can't have it both ways.  I would have a look at the source.  If they're not locking a mutex before accessing the container than it's not threadsafe.

Comment: @Omnifarious Thank you for your comment. I did that and the program crashed with Seg fault. I think abseil doesn't support concurrency then.

Comment: @PaulSanders. That's correct. Thank you.

Comment: @PaulSanders - That's not necessarily true. There are lock-free data structures that only use the atomic operations out there. So, if it's missing any reference to mutexes _or_ atomic operations, then it's not likely thread safe.

Comment: https://greg7mdp.github.io/parallel-hashmap/ built on top of flat_hash_map supports concurrency